# pigeonhole principle problem 3

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Prove: For every group of 1009 positive integers, there exist 2 integers of that group, that their sum or difference divide with 2014 without residue.

where do I start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remainders when $2014$ divides a number is given by the set
$$S = \{0\} \bigcup \{1007\}\displaystyle\bigcup_{r=1}^{1006}\{r,2014-r\} = \bigcup_{k=0}^{1007} S_k$$
where $S$ is written as a union of $1008$ mutually disjoint sets, where $S_0=\{0\}$, $S_{1007} = \{1007\}$ and $S_k = \{k,2014-k\}$. Since there are $1009$ numbers there exists two numbers say $a_1,a_2$ whose remainders fall in the same of the $1008$ sets say some $S_k$. If the remainders of $a_1,a_2$ are the same, then their difference is divisible by $2014$. Else if the remainders are different, then their sum is divisible by $2014$.

Comment: Can u further explain the union definion in the beginning of your proof?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Think about the possible residues when dividing the integers by 2014 (i.e. 0 to 2013). When do two of these residues sum to 0? When do two of these residues lead to a difference of 0? How many different residues could you have?

> Let $N$ be the set of the residues of the 1009 positive integers modulo 2014. Suppose there are two integers with equal residues, i.e., $n_1 \equiv n_2$ mod $2014$. Then $n_1-n_2\equiv0$ mod $2014$. Then assume no two numbers have equal residues (or any number has residue 0). Assume that for any $n_1, n_2\in N$, it is not the case that $n_1+n_2\equiv 0$ mod $2014$. Then for each $n\in N$, its unique inverse mod 2014 is not in $N$. Since there are 1009 unique residues in $N$, there must be 1009 residues not included. However $1009 + 1009 = 2018 > 2014$. This implies that the number of residues of 2014 is greater than 2014, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Why you can say that the inverse is unique?

Comment: And why it is not in N? For sure?

Comment: A fact about number theory is that modulo arithmetic has unique additive inverses. So $2014m_1 + r_1$ is a number with remainder $0\leq r_1 < 2014$ and we want to find $0\leq r_2 < 2014$ such that $2014m_2 + r_2$ sums to a multiple of 2014 with the first number. Then $2014(m_1 + m_2) + (r_1 + r_2)$ is their sum. We are looking for $r_2$ such that $r_1 + r_2 = 0$ or 2014. If $r_1$ is 0, then $r_2$ is 0. If $r_1>0$ then $r_2=2014 - r_1$. This uniquely determines the inverse.

Comment: And we know that the inverses are not in $N$ because we made an assumption (in order to eventually reach a contradiction) that $N$ had no numbers that summed to a multiple of 2014. A number and its inverse will sum to a multiple of 2014, so we must exclude one of them.